# How to make a random number generate in a new cell

Tags: vba, excel

So I want to generate random numbers between 1-13. I have a random number generate Cell A1 but I want to offset a row to put a random number in cell A2 and so forth.

Here is my work so far:

```
Sub randomnumb()
    Dim random_number As Integer
    Randomize
    random_number = Int(13 * Rnd) + 1  
    Cells(1, 1) = random_number
End Sub
```

After being able to do that. I want the random numbers to stop generating after 10 times. I think the "Do Until" method will work but not sure how to do it.

So after playing with it I figured out how to make the next cell generate a random number. I now want to make it where columns B and C generate random numbers starting from Cells B2 and C2. Here is my work so far:

```
Sub randomnumb()

    Dim IntCardOne As Integer

    Randomize

    IntCardOne = Int(13 * Rnd) + 1
    ActiveCell.Value = IntCardOne
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
End Sub
```

Okay. So with the help so far I have done this.

```
Sub test()

    Dim IntHand1 As Integer
    Dim IntHand2 As Integer

    Randomize
     For IntHand1 = 1 To 10
        Cells(IntHand1, 2) = Int(13 * Rnd) + 1
    Next



    Randomize
    For IntHand2 = 1 To 10
        Cells(IntHand2, 3) = Int(13 * Rnd) + 1
    Next IntHand2


End Sub
```

The end goal is to try to make a game called war from the card game.
Of course they generate quickly. Is there a stop function function or method that stops the program from running the code at the end? I also want to offset everything by one row that I way I can put titles for each column. I then want to try to put an If then statement that records a score.

Then hopefully after ten rounds I can print a message box stating the winner.

Okay I finished the program I wanted to make. I have probably stated what I was trying to do earlier but I will repeat it anyway. I was working on trying to make a card game called "War". The spreadsheet had to print numbers and when the user reached a score of 10 he would win and the spreadsheet would stop printing numbers. I want to say thanks for your help. The random number generator you provided me was a good start for the assignment. The professor gave me a 19/20.

Comment: You can get into problems using `ActiveCell`. I strongly suggest you start with the code from my answer. From there, if you want to change the column to B or C change `.Cells(.Rows.Count,1)` to end with `,2)` or `,3)` respectively

Comment: Hi, Can I ask you for help with something else?

Comment: Yep, just create a new question and we'll be happy to help. Please also accept the answer below if it solved your previous problem. Thanks

Comment: Thank you I already have the question posted. Would you like me to post it again?

Comment: No that's fine, I'll take a look soon

Comment: I really appreciate it. I have a final exam this coming Tuesday. So far i am passing the class. I also can email you the file I need help with if you are okay with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you know how many loops you need before you start looping **it's usually easiest to use a `For` loop.**

```
Sub RandomNumber()
    Dim i as Integer
    For i = 1 to 10
        Cells(i,1) = WorksheetFunction.Randbetween(1,13)
    Next i
End Sub
```

If you really want to use `Rnd` and `Randomize`, you'd do it like this

```
Sub RandomNumber()
    Dim i as Integer
    Randomize
    For i = 1 to 10
        Cells(i,1) = Int(13 * Rnd) + 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Update**

One number at a time

```
Sub RandomNumber2()
    Dim lastCell As Range

    'do a ctrl+up from the bottom of column A
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set lastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
    End With

    'move one row down (except for when you have nothing in column A)
    If lastCell.Value <> vbNullString Then
        Set lastCell = lastCell.Offset(1, 0)
    End If

    'place random number in this cell
    lastCell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 13)
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok So far so good but it generates then all too fast. Is there a way to generate the numbers by hitting play one cell at a time?

Comment: Updated, take note of the way I fully qualified the references too `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets...` You'll need to make sure this points to the correct sheet name

Comment: I really appreciate your help. The best one for me seems to be the one that had all of them go quick. The recent one you provided has code that I am not familiar with. I updated my question since trying to write code in the comment section seems a strange.

Comment: Is there a way I can send you my code privately? I don't want students in the future using it.

Comment: Okay you can delete it.